# How to pass gnuradio-like tags in REDHAWK

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm trying to replicate gnuradio-like tags in REDHAWK, SRI looks a bit promising but I'm not sure that I can achieve my goal with that tool.

I'll give a basic example, let's say that I have a component that detects that a certain signal starts at a position. This component doesn't do anything else but this. I'd like to pass this information onto the second component so that It can start working from that position forward.

Is there any way to mark the specific position in the bulkio stream and pass it to the next component?

gnuradio has tags, that can pass any userdata between computational components, and it's precise to the bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using keywords? They are part of the SRI data structures and are a list of key value pairs.  The key is a user defined string and the value is any standard type (double, string, int, etc).  Here is how front end devices use them to pass along filter bandwidth and frequency information: http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainap6.html#x25-542000F.5.2

Comment: I didn't write any code, but it seems to me that it wouldn't work. I need to tag specific bytes. I'm not certain how to do this. I mean, sure I can add a custom keyword, but how does the next component know which byte it refers to?

Comment: Unless the data you are passing is packetized already, I would not use byte location to label the start of a signal. If you were to pass the signal through a filter or up/down sampler then the location of the signal start would shift in the array. REDHAWK supports highly precise timing passed in each push of data through Precision UTC Time struct: https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/core-framework/blob/develop-2.0/bulkioInterfaces/idl/ossie/BULKIO/bulkioDataTypes.idl#L65 If the data you are pushing around is burst like in nature though you could also use BurstIO rather than BulkIO

Comment: I guess this is what I had in mind. So I would tag the start position by setting a keyword with the timestamp of the position. I'm still a bit worried that it might not work 100% precisely. Sure enough any filter that modifies the data positions should rework the tags too, like you said.

Comment: Just to be clear, any filter that modifies the data does NOT need to update your unique time tags. A generic asset like a filter should not need to know about your specific keyword names. It only needs to update the time fields that are part of the standard SRI meaning x-start, x-delta etc. Your keywords indicate a moment in time that an event occurred and that will always be true and never need updating as long as the standard fields which indicate a reference to time are.